# Can I upgrade Neo4j from version 4.2.4 straight to version 4.4.26?

Tags: neo4j, version, upgrade

I have neo4j Community edition installed on Windows, currently version 4.2.4 and need to upgrade it. The neo4j documentation suggests 4.2 -> 4.3 -> 4.4 but the only version 4 available to download is now 4.4.26

The upgrade instructions are the same, can I just follow them but jump from 4.2 to 4.4?

https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/version-4/understanding-upgrades-migration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I frequently use `neo4j-admin copy` to migrate databases, and it works really well.

It recreates a fresh copy of your existing DB into the target format of the new Neo4j version.

There is a tutorial describing how to use it to migrate from `3.5` to `4.x`. That works the same way for `4.2` to `4.4` :
https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/version-4/tutorials/online-backup-copy-database/

**Update**: this ^^ works only for with the enterprise edition. With the community edition, you can upgrade 4.2 -> 4.3 -> 4.4 using a 4.3 community version downloadable [here](https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&release=4.3.23&flavour=winzip).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The docs state _upgrade/migrate a database (from Community or Enterprise) to a later version of Neo4j Enterprise edition_ whereas I need to go to a Community edition - is it likely to work?

Comment: ha, looks like `neo4j-admin copy` only works with enterprise. I updated the answer with a downloadable link for 4.3

Comment: Thank you!! I could not find the 4.3 download before